# Angular date filter not working

Tags: angularjs, date, filter

Not working or I'm not using it correctly. I have a date saved in mongodb (which is correct) as:

`"2015-12-10T12:00:00.000Z"`

I have an angular filter of date as:

`date: 'medium'` that shows **Dec 10, 2015 7:00:00 AM** in the view

`date: 'medium' : +0500` bumpeds it to  **Dec 10, 2015 5:00:00 PM**

`date: 'medium' : -0500` it shows as: **Dec 10, 2015 7:00:00 AM** AGAIN

How the hell do I get it to show at 12pm?! lol I'm on EST time

Comment: you want it to **not** adjust for the time zone basically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Z` at the end means "UTC". So, that date represents the instant that is displayed as 2015-12-10T12:00:00.000 in the UTC time zone.

And you want to display it as if you were in the UTC time zone, since you don't want the time part to be different from the one it has in UTC.

So, use UTC as the time zone:

```
date:'medium':'UTC'
```

Output:

```
Dec 10, 2015 12:00:00 PM
```

Comment: You learn something new everyday.  This is a much better answer.  I didn't know that was a date option for angular's date filter.

Comment: So I guess I don't get why it was shown by angular as 7am when just using 'medium'. And +5 -5 forced it to 5PM and back to 7am without every touching 12. It's like it was acting like 12pm but showing as 7am... why?

Comment: By default, your browser timezone is used. Since your browser timezone is EST, i.e. UTC-05:00, when it's 12:00 in UTC, it's 07:00AM in EST. If you tell the filter to format the date as if you were in UTC+05:00 (i.e. as if you lived in the Maldives or in Uzbekistan), then it formats it as 5:00PM. Using -05:00 is the same as not using any explicit time zone in your case, since your browser is at -05:00.

Answer (score 0):

#### filter

Create a custom filter first:

```
.filter( 'trimDateTime', function(){
    function(ds){
        var z = ds.indexOf('Z')
        return ds.substr(0, z)
    }
 }
```

#### html

Then apply 2 filters to the data

```
<p>{{ dateString | trimDateTime | date: 'medium' }}</p>
```

#### why

Angular filters are powerful mechanisms for leaving your data intact but rendering a special way.  You could have easily trimmed the 'Z' from your date string but then later on, another UX might be expecting that data to be intact.

#### codepen

http://codepen.io/jusopi/pen/pgvOBr